# Failing to fetch dynamic data from firestore using getStaticPaths in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js

When I fetch data from firebase firestore using getStaticProps, it works perfectly but when I try implementing the logic of getting the details of each single item using getStaticPaths, I fail and get a 404 page. This is how my [id].js code looks like currently.

```
import React from 'react'
import { db } from '@/Firebase';
import {collection, getDoc} from "firebase/firestore";

const reference = collection(db, "abantu");

export const getStaticPaths= async () => {
    const umuntu = await getDoc(reference);

    const paths = umuntu.docs.map(doc => {
        return {
            params: { id: doc.id }
        }
    })

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false
    }

}

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
    const id = context.params.id;
    const data = await getDoc(reference) + id;
    
    return {
        props: {
            umuntu: data
        }
    }
}

function Details({umuntu}) {
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>{umuntu.ibizo}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Details
```

I dont quite get where my logic is going wrong but where could I be going wrong?.

Comment: Everything should be working, can you share a log of your paths array in the `getStaticProps` function?

Comment: Also not sure what will be the type of data here:`const data = await getDoc(reference) + id`. Seems like the `getDoc(reference)` would return an object and you are adding the `id` with + operator

Comment: @score30 I get this back "on-demand-entries-client.js?845c:45          GET http://localhost:3000/peopleBfCIPmHFkjpMViAMGLRm 404 (Not Found)". I do get that line const data = await getDoc(reference) + id will not work now but I am wondering how best to use the id

Comment: The `getStaticPath` should work to be honest and should get all the paths based on `umuntu.docs`. For finding the right page props for each of the paths in the `getStaticProps` see my response to the question

Answer (score 0):

For finding the right page props for each of the paths that you generate from the database in the `getStaticPaths` function, you should be able to find each of the pages information based on the `id` field you are getting from each path, see it here:

```
export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const umuntu = await getDoc(reference);
  const data = umuntu.docs.find((pageData) => pageData.id === id); // this will find the right page based on the id passed via page path

  return {
    props: {
      data
    },
  };
};

function Details({ data }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.ibizo}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Details;
```

Comment: It is very strange. I just updated the code but it is still giving me a 404 page although it is now doing something which it was not doing before, which is putting the id of the clicked item in the url so at least it knows the item selected but now the problem is rendering it onto the screen

Comment: Can you share the value of umuntu `const umuntu = await getDoc(reference);`? I want to see which value we are using for setting the paths urls

Comment: I dont quite get what you mean. You mean I console log it out? It returns nothing when I do that. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I want to see what property of the umuntu object you are trying to use as the url for for the pages? What do you want to pus it in the url bar to view the page and you get a 404 error? Does this value exist in the `umuntu` object?

Comment: oh its the id it just puts the item's id next to the route name on the url like so "http://localhost:3000/people2dLE0tWsrH36fnsfC4". I think thats for showing that it has opened the specific item inside umuntu

Comment: Gotcha, so you still get 404 when you put in something like:`localhost:3000/people2dLE0tWsrH36fnsfC4`?

Comment: yes it says the page cannot be found. oh and I'd like to say thanks for taking time out to help me. I appreaciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251222/discussion-between-score30-and-vuyi).